# Does Shrine Storage S3 supports options for IAM Profiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, shrine

His there an option that can be sent as an argument of `Shrine::Storage::S3.new` that sets the use of an IAM Profile to `true`, just like Carrierwave does?

For example:

```rb
s3_options = {
  use_iam_profile: true,
}

Shrine::Storage::S3.new(
  upload_options: { server_side_encryption: "AES256" },
  **s3_options,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrine's S3 storage supports any configuration that [`Aws::S3::Client#initialize`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#initialize-instance_method) supports. If I remember correctly, in order to use the IAM profile, you should simply not pass any credentials (and specify only the bucket name).

```
Shrine::Storage::S3.new(
  bucket: "your-bucket-name",
  upload_options: { ... },
)
```